# Is pygame.display.flip() guaranteed to copy (as opposed to flip/alternate) buffers

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame for a 2D game. I noticed that I don't have to render my whole scene every frame. If I incrementally draw my scene and flip it regularly, I obtain what I want.

However, I recall ages ago on SDL/OpenGL, depending on hardware flags you could get either a flip between the surfaces or a copy of your back buffer to your front buffer.

Is there any garantee on which one you get when calling pygame.display.flip()?
Any way to force one behaviour over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass `HWSURFACE | DOUBLEBUF` to [pygame.display.set_mode](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), you'll only have the one buffer to draw in. This corresponds directly to SDL 1.2's [SDL_SetVideoMode](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html). Not using double buffering may lead to drawing directly in the front buffer, which is visible; traditionally (mainly in consoles and home computers) this was done during the vertical blanking period to avoid artifacts. Using double buffering the flip will synchronise that way, to avoid tearing. The flag selects which interface your program sees; there may still be double buffering at OS or hardware level without it, and the double buffering may be software emulated even with it.